# When would one use Un-named shared memory?

Tags: c++, windows

When would you choose to use un-named shared memory in windows?

it seems to me that message passing between threads is not very useful. One can instead pass a pointer to a struct/variable to the worker threads, and use that as shared memory instead, rather than calling the CreateFileMapping system call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason to use unnamed shared memory is to restrict access to the file mapping to only those processes who are given a handle to it by the creating process.  This avoid two problems:

- any process that knows the name and has sufficient access to create a mapped file can squat on your named object, preventing or interfering with its legitimate use - this allows a denial of service attack.
- accidental rather than malicious name clashes.

When you don't use a name, you can be sure that only processes that you want to have access, get it.  From the [MSDN docs for CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> A single file mapping object can be
>   shared by multiple processes through
>   inheriting the handle at process
>   creation, duplicating the handle, or
>   opening the file mapping object by
>   name.

Answer (score 3):

Section objects (aka "file mapping objects") are not just used to share memory between processes. The most obvious use of section objects is to map in a file to do I/O, and giving the objects names wouldn't be very useful in most cases. For unnamed pagefile-backed sections ("shared memory") you can still make child processes inherit the handle so they can use the sections.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'map in a file to do I/O'? If its something like a text file, cant we just pass a handle to the file to threads that need it via LPVOID?

Comment: I'm saying that you don't need named section objects for mapping in files. That answers your question, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass handles to unnamed objects across process boundaries. That is to say, you can actually create an unnamed memory map in your application, and access it from another *without* using a name!

Look at the `DuplicateHandle` call, which can be used to pass handles to unnamed objects across process boundaries.

Comment: Why not just use a named object in this case? Is there an advantage of using an un-named one? We can then get a handle to the named shared memory as long as we know the name of the shared memory

Comment: No *real* reason, but it does let you dynamically create handles without worrying about naming conflicts. Plus, you don't need to place objects in the `Golbal` namespace, and can also get access to objects that have security permissions enabled preventing anyone else from opening it.

Comment: @aCuria - we do this in our client-server application. The server creates a named piece of shared memory that the clients can look for. For each connection, the server creates an piece of unnamed shared memory for that connection and passes it the handle. Then the client and server can communicate using the unnamed piece. This allows any number of connections to the same server and each one doesn't affect any other.

Comment: @Graeme - while that's exactly the situation I advertised, I found creating a named pipe GUID_X where X is the client id, and instead of passing the handle we pass the X (client id) to the newly-connected client. Both work equally well, I guess.